# How do I create this Pandas column matching most columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame (150,000 x 25) of financial transactions. Many (not all of these transactions) are reversed at a later date. I would like to create a new column which identifies when the transaction was reversed.

I have tried a few functions like drop_duplicates() and duplicated(), against the category, type, and source columns, but can't quite narrow down my solutions. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd

d_in = {'key' : ['81371453', '93045710', '22123452', '18233745', '84933451', '95832374', '20283456', '20239485', '95843745'], 
        'date' : ['20200901', '20200901', '20200902', '20200902', '20200902','20200903', '20200904', '20200905', '20200905'],
        'category' : ['Z293', 'B993', 'Z293', 'B993', 'W884', 'C123', 'V332', 'C123', 'V332'], 
        'type' : ['tools', 'supplies', 'tools', 'supplies', 'repairs', 'custom', 'misc', 'custom', 'misc'], 
        'source' : ['Q112', 'E443', 'Q112', 'E443', 'P443', 'B334', 'E449', 'B334', 'E449'], 
        'amount' : [123.21, 3.12, -123.21, -3.12, 9312.00, 312.23, -13.23, -312.23, 13.23]}

df_in = pd.DataFrame(data=d_in)


d_out = {'key' : ['81371453', '93045710', '22123452', '18233745', '84933451', '95832374', '20283456', '20239485', '95843745'], 
    'date' : ['20200901', '20200901', '20200902', '20200902', '20200902','20200903', '20200904', '20200905', '20200905'],
    'category' : ['Z293', 'B993', 'Z293', 'B993', 'W884', 'C123', 'V332', 'C123', 'V332'], 
    'type' : ['tools', 'supplies', 'tools', 'supplies', 'repairs', 'custom', 'misc', 'custom', 'misc'], 
    'source' : ['Q112', 'E443', 'Q112', 'E443', 'P443', 'B334', 'E449', 'B334', 'E449'], 
    'amount' : [123.21, 3.12, -123.21, -3.12, 9312.00, 312.23, -13.23, -312.23, 13.23], 
    'reversed' : ['20200902', '20200902', '20200901', '20200901', 'none', '20200905', '20200905', '20200903', '20200904']}

df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=d_out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the max and min date per group and set the min to the max and the max to the min. If there is only one per group, then set to `None`:

```
gb = df_in.groupby(['category', 'type', 'source'])
maxx = gb['date'].transform(max)
minn = gb['date'].transform(min)
df_in['reversed'] = np.where(df_in['date'] == maxx, minn, maxx)
df_in['reversed'] = df_in['reversed'].mask(gb['date'].transform('size') == 1, None)
df_in
Out[1]: 
        key      date category      type source   amount  reversed
0  81371453  20200901     Z293     tools   Q112   123.21  20200902
1  93045710  20200901     B993  supplies   E443     3.12  20200902
2  22123452  20200902     Z293     tools   Q112  -123.21  20200901
3  18233745  20200902     B993  supplies   E443    -3.12  20200901
4  84933451  20200902     W884   repairs   P443  9312.00      None
5  95832374  20200903     C123    custom   B334   312.23  20200905
6  20283456  20200904     V332      misc   E449   -13.23  20200905
7  20239485  20200905     C123    custom   B334  -312.23  20200903
8  95843745  20200905     V332      misc   E449    13.23  20200904
```

Comment: This seems like a clean solution, and is reproduced in the dataset I provided. However, in my actual dataset, minn and maxx are populated with NaN. Looking closer at my groupby statement.

Comment: Then, you might have some NaN values in one of your columns. You can do: `df_in[df_in['category'].isnull()]` and then replace `category` with other columns to inspect row-by-row OR just do `df_in.info()` and see which columns have nulls on a high level.

Comment: As a quick solution, from there, you can use `df_in['category'] = df_in['category'].ffill()`... again you can replace 'category' with whatever column. This would just be to confirm that the solution works, but figuring out what you want to do with null values may be a different problem.

Comment: You were right--each column contained quite a few NaN values. So I just used the fillna() function. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

@David Erickson has an excellent answer, but you can make it more robust by grouping on the absolute value of the amount. This would be useful if it's possible for multiple transactions to share the same category, type, and source, but have different spending amounts.

```py
df_in['amount_abs'] = df_in['amount'].abs()
gb = df_in.groupby(['category', 'type', 'source', 'amount_abs'])
maxx = gb['date'].transform(max)
minn = gb['date'].transform(min)
df_in['reversed'] = np.where(df_in['date'] == maxx, minn, maxx)
df_in['reversed'] = df_in['reversed'].mask(gb['date'].transform('size') == 1, None)
df_in = df_in.drop('amount_abs', axis=1)
```

Comment: That is true. Ideally, the source data would have a transaction id # to group on, as the amount could also be the same leading to duplicates in rare circumstances.

Comment: This was a helpful contribution, and I used the absolute column as suggested. The source data's transaction id isn't as convenient as David Erickson suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `transform` with `reversed([::-1])`

```
s = df.groupby(['category','type','source'])['amount'].transform('sum')
date = df.groupby(['category','type','source'],sort=False)['date'].transform(lambda x : x.tolist()[::-1])
df.loc[s.eq(0), 'reversed'] = date
df
Out[95]: 
        key      date category      type source   amount  reversed
0  81371453  20200901     Z293     tools   Q112   123.21  20200902
1  93045710  20200901     B993  supplies   E443     3.12  20200902
2  22123452  20200902     Z293     tools   Q112  -123.21  20200901
3  18233745  20200902     B993  supplies   E443    -3.12  20200901
4  84933451  20200902     W884   repairs   P443  9312.00       NaN
5  95832374  20200903     C123    custom   B334   312.23  20200905
6  20283456  20200904     V332      misc   E449   -13.23  20200905
7  20239485  20200905     C123    custom   B334  -312.23  20200903
8  95843745  20200905     V332      misc   E449    13.23  20200904
```