# Create Pandas column which finds and returns matching data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame (150,000 x 25) of financial transactions. This DataFrame represents a type of financial holding account, such that transactions often "pass through" this ledger. For example (below), the row in position 0 shows a -$123.21 transaction. The row in position 2 is the corresponding (or "coupled") transaction for +$123.21, and matching the category, type, and source.

My goal is to create a new column to identify the key of the "coupled" transaction. Thus, the "coupling key" of row 0 is the key from row 2, and vice versa.

Note that the rows in positions 9-14 preclude solutions which search for min and max matches ([@David Erickson previously provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64759708/530160) an excellent answer along those lines). The row in position 9 shows a +$10 transaction. It is coupled with the first -$10, found in position 11 (rather than the transaction found in position 14). In this way, each transaction is coupled with either zero or one other transactions, but not more than one.

```
import pandas as pd

d_in = {'key' : ['80000001', '80000002', '80000003', '80000004', '80000005', '80000006', '80000007', '80000008', '80000009', '80000010', '80000011', '80000012', '80000013', '80000014', '80000015'], 
        'date' : ['20200901', '20200901', '20200902', '20200902', '20200902','20200903', '20200904', '20200905', '20200905', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906'],
        'category' : ['Z293', 'B993', 'Z293', 'B993', 'W884', 'C123', 'V332', 'C123', 'V332', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213'], 
        'type' : ['tools', 'supplies', 'tools', 'supplies', 'repairs', 'custom', 'misc', 'custom', 'misc', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology'], 
        'source' : ['Q112', 'E443', 'Q112', 'E443', 'P443', 'B334', 'E449', 'B334', 'E449', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32'], 
        'amount' : [-123.21, 3.12, 123.21, -3.12, 9312.00, 312.23, -13.23, -312.23, 13.23, 10, 10, -10, -10, 10, -10]}

df_in = pd.DataFrame(data=d_in)


d_out = {'key' : ['80000001', '80000002', '80000003', '80000004', '80000005', '80000006', '80000007', '80000008', '80000009', '80000010', '80000011', '80000012', '80000013', '80000014', '80000015'], 
        'date' : ['20200901', '20200901', '20200902', '20200902', '20200902','20200903', '20200904', '20200905', '20200905', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906'],
        'category' : ['Z293', 'B993', 'Z293', 'B993', 'W884', 'C123', 'V332', 'C123', 'V332', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213'], 
        'type' : ['tools', 'supplies', 'tools', 'supplies', 'repairs', 'custom', 'misc', 'custom', 'misc', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology'], 
        'source' : ['Q112', 'E443', 'Q112', 'E443', 'P443', 'B334', 'E449', 'B334', 'E449', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32'], 
        'amount' : [-123.21, 3.12, 123.21, -3.12, 9312.00, 312.23, -13.23, -312.23, 13.23, 10, 10, -10, -10, 10, -10], 
    'coupling_key' : ['80000003', '80000004', '80000001', '80000002', 'none', '80000008', '80000009', '80000006', '80000007', '80000012', '80000013', '80000010', '80000011', '80000015', '80000014']}

df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=d_out)
```

Most solutions I have explored involve pandas groupby function. I am currently considering the groupby(...).nth(...) function. I suspect the solution may also involve .mask or .duplicated().

Comment: Please paste the code you have tried so far and the point where you are stuck

Comment: Edited the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, trying to stay with 'pure pandas' functions (whatever that means!)

To understand the below, here are the steps

1. we group by 'category', 'type', 'source', and abs('amount')
2. within each group, we would have rows with the same abs amount but different signs. So we then group by 'amount', label rows within positives from 1 to n and within negatives from 1 to n consequently (hence the `cumcount()`) then
3. ...group by matching first element in positives vs first in negatives, second in positives vs second in negatives, etc
4. group_match will have a list of ['key1', 'key2'] that matched in step 3
5. The rest is just pulling these lists together (we also want ['key2','key1'] for each ['key1','key2'] hence the line `reversed(..)` in it), converting into a dataframe, and joining to the original one

Step 5 can probably be done more elegantly but this works

```
match = []
for _, df2 in df_in.groupby([df_in['category'], df_in['type'], df_in['source'], df_in['amount'].abs()], as_index=False):
   group_match = df2.groupby(df2.groupby(['amount']).cumcount())['key'].apply(list)
   match.extend(group_match)
   match.extend([list(reversed(m)) for m in group_match])

match_df = pd.DataFrame(data = match, columns = ['key', 'coupling_key']).drop_duplicates()
df_out = df_in.merge(match_df, on='key')
```

generates the required df_out:

```
    key         date        category type       source  amount  coupling_key
0   80000001    20200901    Z293    tools       Q112    -123.21 80000003
1   80000002    20200901    B993    supplies    E443    3.12    80000004
2   80000003    20200902    Z293    tools       Q112    123.21  80000001
3   80000004    20200902    B993    supplies    E443    -3.12   80000002
4   80000005    20200902    W884    repairs     P443    9312.00 None
5   80000006    20200903    C123    custom      B334    312.23  80000008
6   80000007    20200904    V332    misc        E449    -13.23  80000009
7   80000008    20200905    C123    custom      B334    -312.23 80000006
8   80000009    20200905    V332    misc        E449    13.23   80000007
9   80000010    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    10.00   80000012
10  80000011    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    10.00   80000013
11  80000012    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    -10.00  80000010
12  80000013    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    -10.00  80000011
13  80000014    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    10.00   80000015
14  80000015    20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    -10.00  80000014
```

If there are zeroes in `amount` column and they should be matched per the comments below, we can modify the loop as follows

```
for _, df2 in df_in.groupby([df_in['category'], df_in['type'], df_in['source'], df_in['amount'].abs()], as_index=False):
   if (df2['amount'].iloc[0] == 0):
      group_match = df2.groupby([i//2 for i in range(len(df2))])['key'].apply(list)
   else:
      group_match = df2.groupby(df2.groupby(['amount']).cumcount())['key'].apply(list)
   match.extend(group_match)
   match.extend([list(reversed(m)) for m in group_match])
```

with the `df_in` extended as such (note three 0 rows at the end:

```
d_in = {'key' : ['80000001', '80000002', '80000003', '80000004', '80000005', '80000006', '80000007', '80000008', '80000009', '80000010', '80000011', '80000012', '80000013', '80000014', '80000015', '1', '2', '3'], 
        'date' : ['20200901', '20200901', '20200902', '20200902', '20200902','20200903', '20200904', '20200905', '20200905', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906', '20200906'],
        'category' : ['Z293', 'B993', 'Z293', 'B993', 'W884', 'C123', 'V332', 'C123', 'V332', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213', 'Z213'], 
        'type' : ['tools', 'supplies', 'tools', 'supplies', 'repairs', 'custom', 'misc', 'custom', 'misc', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology', 'technology','technology', 'technology', 'technology'], 
        'source' : ['Q112', 'E443', 'Q112', 'E443', 'P443', 'B334', 'E449', 'B334', 'E449', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32', 'QQ32'], 
        'amount' : [-123.21, 3.12, 123.21, -3.12, 9312.00, 312.23, -13.23, -312.23, 13.23, 10, 10, -10, -10, 10, -10,0,0,0]}
```

we get (ignoring the same rows as before)

```
    key date    category    type    source  amount  coupling_key
15  1   20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    0.00    2
16  2   20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    0.00    1
17  3   20200906    Z213    technology  QQ32    0.00    None
```

Comment: This post is along the lines I was considering, thank you for your response!

Comment: I am finding that this solution is not controlled for zero amounts. Regrettably, I did not ask for this condition in my original post. How difficult would it be to rework this code to control for zero amounts?

Comment: what's the rule with zero amounts? eg you can filter them out as the first step

Comment: Thanks for asking. The rule is that zero amounts should be coupled along the same rules as non-zero amounts. In other words, within the given conditions, the first zero should be coupled to the second, the third zero to the fourth, and so on.

Comment: all zeroes for the same category etc will end up in the same group (same `df2`) inside the loop, so looks like we need an `if(df2['amount']==0)` condition in the loop to treat this separately case separately. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

**Step 1**: Setting up `transform` function:

```
def coupling(ser):
    keys = ser.index
    values = ser.values
    couples = [None] * len(ser)
    free = {*range(len(ser))}
    while free:
        i = min(free)
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(ser):
            if (values[j] == -values[i]
                    and j in free):
                couples[i], couples[j] = keys[j], keys[i]
                free.remove(j)
                break
            j += 1
        free.remove(i)
    return couples
```

**Step 2**: Application to groups:

```
df_out = df_in.set_index('key')
group = ['category', 'type', 'source']
df_out['coupling_key'] = (df_out[group + ['amount']]
                          .groupby(group)
                          .transform(coupling))
df_out.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
         key      date category        type source   amount coupling_key
0   80000001  20200901     Z293       tools   Q112  -123.21     80000003
1   80000002  20200901     B993    supplies   E443     3.12     80000004
2   80000003  20200902     Z293       tools   Q112   123.21     80000001
3   80000004  20200902     B993    supplies   E443    -3.12     80000002
4   80000005  20200902     W884     repairs   P443  9312.00         None
5   80000006  20200903     C123      custom   B334   312.23     80000008
6   80000007  20200904     V332        misc   E449   -13.23     80000009
7   80000008  20200905     C123      custom   B334  -312.23     80000006
8   80000009  20200905     V332        misc   E449    13.23     80000007
9   80000010  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32    10.00     80000012
10  80000011  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32    10.00     80000013
11  80000012  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32   -10.00     80000010
12  80000013  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32   -10.00     80000011
13  80000014  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32    10.00     80000015
14  80000015  20200906     Z213  technology   QQ32   -10.00     80000014
```

(I'm assuming that the `date` column is ordered like in the example.)